# Using the RecursiveIteratorIterator to show all the child files and maps

Tags: php, iterator

I am currently working with the RecursiveIteratorIterator and the RecursiveDirectoryIterator to look through all the folders and files in my project folder (it starts from the project root folder).
The point of this tool is to find all the file differences. The problem is, it works on my localhost but not on the server nor the systems of my colleague's.

**I am on PHP 7.1.0, just like my colleague's**

I am using the following code for the iterator

```
new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $startingPoint ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );
```

the '$startingPoint' is the root location of the project.

The full code is

```
$startingPoint = realpath(__DIR__ . '../../'); # project root

#uncomment for list of files *down here*
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $startingPoint ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );

foreach( (array) $objects as $name => $object  ) {
    if( strpos( $object->getPathName(), '.git' ) == FALSE && strpos( 
       $object->getPathName(), '.idea' ) == FALSE && strpos( $object->getPathName(), 'uploads' ) == FALSE && ! ( $object->getBaseName() == '.' || $object->getBaseName() == '..' ) ) {

    $fileLocation = str_replace( array( $startingPoint . '\\', '\\' ), array( '', '/' ), $object->getPathName() );

    #uncomment when generating a new list of directories
//                $filesShouldExist[] = [ "loc" => $fileLocation, "size" => $object->getSize() ];
    }
}
```

It will just stop at the creation of the iterators, and no errors will be given.
Please note, this code works on (my) windows, however, not on mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PHP's documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

> **__DIR__** The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
>   dirname(__FILE__). **This directory name does not have a trailing slash
>   unless it is the root directory.**

So, add a slash to the path:

```
$startingPoint = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../'); # note the added slash at the start of the string literal
```

and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Turns out i only needed the __DIR__ . '/../' in the realpath to do so. Thank you!